# HWIOAuthBundle registered in AppKernel, but still not found

Tags: php, symfony, hwioauthbundle

my bundle is registered , but I still get this error in `'AppKernel.php'`
at this line: `new HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\HWIOAuthBundle()`
My error:

> ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 13: Attempted to load
>   class "HWIOAuthBundle" from namespace "HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle". Did
>   you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

I also done: `composer require hwi/oauth-bundle`.Where could be my mistake?

```
    use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
    use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;
    use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle;

    class AppKernel extends Kernel
    {
        public function registerBundles()
        {
            $bundles = array(

                new HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\HWIOAuthBundle(),
                new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
                new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
                new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
                new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
                new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
                new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
                new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
                new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
                new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
                new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle(),
            );

            if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'), true)) {
                $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
                $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
                $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
                $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
            }

            return $bundles;
        }

        public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
        {
            $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
        }
    }
```

My `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "hwi/oauth-bundle": "^0.5.3",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.7-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing `use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle;` and move `new HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\HWIOAuthBundle(),` to the end, not the front. Then do a cache:clear

Comment: Still same, same error just in another line `ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 24:`

Comment: Are you sure about your installation ? Is the directory `hwi` in your `vendor` ?

Comment: Yes I have `hwi` catalog in my vendor folder `vendor/hwi/oauth-bundle` with all other catalogs and with `HWIOAuthBundle.php` file

Comment: It's strange, just test a similar configuration on my machine and it works. Maybe test a `composer dump-autoload'  or a good old cache clean ?

Comment: Am making new symfony project second time and still same error

Answer (score 1):

To be sure that this is not a cache problem, can you follow this process please?

- Remove /vendor directory
- Remove /app/cache content
- Remove /app/bootstrap.php.cache
- Remove composer.lock
- Run command composer self-update && composer update -vvv

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Now I lost my `bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: Can you copy your composer.json please?
For build your bootstrap.php.cache, juste comment  new HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\HWIOAuthBundle(), 
But it will not solve your problem. This is either a configuration problem at the level of your project or at the level of the composer.json

Comment: Also, you can remove "use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle;" in your AppKernel.php